# Website layout for mobile looks fine on emulator but not on actual mobile device

Tags: html, css

I just started learning html/css/javascript and decided to throw together a website for practice. I now know that a lot of the approaches I took in creating this website are seen as bad practice, which is why I will not continue to do them. What i'm having issues with is getting the mobile layout I see on Firefox's mobile emulator to appear as is on an actual mobile device. Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

[Website Files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d6emlme37x08wge/AAA-ot9OeRGSYauRomMGHd6Ia?dl=0)

Comment: Already found the answer to my problem. The issue has little to no chance of being replicated so it adds nothing if the question remains here. Please delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers have some basal CSS-styling already: if you type in a `<h1>sentence</h1>` like this without the basic HTML elements, Chrome will still deliver the webpage.

I built a basic web-design framework like Bootstrap, and these three lines are critical in making a responsive webpage. Make sure to add them at the top of the `<head></head>`.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

The dropbox files wouldn't open, so I haven't seen your work. Try adding these and see if it works.

Comment: I tried to add the meta tags you provided but had no luck. I think the dropbox files should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag to your pages, in the <head> element:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

I had this issue with Bootstrap awhile ago and then found this nifty answer online. I also would recommend using something like Bootstrap or Materialize.

Comment: I don't have that exact meta tag, but I have something very similar already. I thought it would fix my problem but it kept persisting.